# Trying to get the right value answer for my code

Tags: java, netbeans

Below is the code i have written for a student class and main method. I am having two problems. Firstly, when i try and put main as its own class, if fails to run and compile saying there is an erroneous error with main not being able to reference and create the student classes within main.

Second problem, the last line where it prints out the highest average mark, always prints out 0.0, and i cannot for the life of me work out why.

Can anyone give me the solution to either problems?

I am using NetBeans.

```
package student;

public class Student {

    private String name, id;
    private int[] score = new int[3];
    public Student()
        {

        }
        public Student(String stName, String stID, int stScore[]) {
        this.name = stName;
        this.id = stID;
        this.score = stScore;    
    }
    public void setName(String nameIn)
    {
        name = nameIn;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public double avScore()
    {
        double total = 0;
        int to = 0;
        int adder = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<score.length; i++)
        {
            score[i] = adder;
            total = total + adder;
        }
        total = total / score.length;
        return total;
    }
    public void printOut() {
        System.out.println("Student Name is: " + name) ;
        System.out.println("Student ID is: " + id);
        System.out.println("Student scores are: ");
        for (int i=0; i<score.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(score[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        Student stud1 = new Student("Nico Del Pellegrino", "up660537", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
        Student stud2 = new Student("Dylan Scott", "up652312", new int[] {5, 7, 13});
        stud1.printOut();
        stud2.printOut();
        Student stud3 = new Student();
        stud3.id = "up645658";
        stud3.name = "Alex Barrett";
        stud3.score = new int[]{5, 10, 15};
        stud3.printOut();
        double stud1Score = stud1.avScore();
        double stud2Score = stud2.avScore();
        double stud3Score = stud3.avScore();
        double[] scoreList = {stud1Score, stud2Score, stud3Score};
        double highestMark = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<scoreList.length;)
        {
            if(scoreList[i]>highestMark)
            {
                highestMark = scoreList[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The highest average mark is: " + highestMark);

}
}
```

EDIT:
This is the code in its separate classes, and the error message that occurs when running main.

```
package student;

public class Student {

private String name, id;
private int[] score = new int[3];

public Student() {
}

public Student(String stName, String stID, int stScore[]) {
    this.name = stName;
    this.id = stID;
    this.score = stScore;
}

public void setName(String nameIn) {
    name = nameIn;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double avScore() {
    double total = 0;
    int to = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        total = total + score[i];
    }
    total = total / score.length;
    return total;
}

public void printOut() {
    System.out.println("Student Name is: " + name);
    System.out.println("Student ID is: " + id);
    System.out.println("Student scores are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(score[i]);
    }
}
}


package Student;

import Student.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args []) {
    //Create two student objects stud1 and stud2 here
    Student stud1 = new Student("Nico Del Pellegrino", "up660537", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
    Student stud2 = new Student("Dylan Scott", "up652312", new int[] {5, 7, 13});
    //Display information for the two objects
    stud1.printOut();
    stud2.printOut();
    //Create third student object stud3 here
    Student stud3 = new Student();
    // change object id
    stud3.id = "up645658";
    // change object name
    stud3.name = "Alex Barrett";
    // change object exam scores
    stud3.score = new int[]{5, 10, 15};
    stud3.printOut();
    // Find out which student is with the highest average score
    int stud1Score = stud1.avScore();
    int stud2Score = stud2.avScore();
    int stud3Score = stud3.avScore();
    //Display his/her details here
    }
    }


    //run:
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous         tree //type: Student.Student
    //  at Student.Main.main(Main.java:9)
    //Java Result: 1
    //BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What is the "erroneous error" message when you attempt to place `main` in its own class?

Comment: Is the new class that houses `main` in the package `student`? if not you will have to import Student `import student.Student`

Comment: In the main class, it is a package of student, and I do import Student, neither way it works, it says it is erroneous tree type Student.Student, the note code at the bottom of the edit is the rror message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment on this line is incorrect:

```
score[i] = adder;
```

You initialized `adder` to `0`, so you are effectively placing zeroes throughout your array.  No wonder you get `0.0` for the average.  Instead of

```
score[i] = adder;
total = total + adder;
```

You don't even need `adder`, just use:

```
total = total + score[i];
```